# How to delete the first row of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset with 11 columns with over a 1000 rows each. The columns were labeled V1, V2, V11, etc..
I replaced the names with something more useful to me using the "c" command.
I didn't realize that row 1 also contained labels for each column and my actual data starts on row 2.

Is there a way to delete row 1 and decrement?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Keep the labels from your original file like this:

```
df = read.table('data.txt', header = T)
```

If you have columns named x and y, you can address them like this:

```
df$x
df$y
```

If you'd like to actually delete the first row from a data.frame, you can use negative indices like this:

```
df = df[-1,]
```

If you'd like to delete a column from a data.frame, you can assign NULL to it:

```
df$x = NULL
```

Here are some simple examples of how to create and manipulate a data.frame in R:

```
# create a data.frame with 10 rows
> x = rnorm(10)
> y = runif(10)
> df = data.frame( x, y )

# write it to a file
> write.table( df, 'test.txt', row.names = F, quote = F )

# read a data.frame from a file: 
> read.table( df, 'test.txt', header = T )

> df$x
 [1] -0.95343778 -0.63098637 -1.30646529  1.38906143  0.51703237 -0.02246754
 [7]  0.20583548  0.21530721  0.69087460  2.30610998
> df$y
 [1] 0.66658148 0.15355851 0.60098886 0.14284576 0.20408723 0.58271061
 [7] 0.05170994 0.83627336 0.76713317 0.95052671

> df$x = x
> df
            y           x
1  0.66658148 -0.95343778
2  0.15355851 -0.63098637
3  0.60098886 -1.30646529
4  0.14284576  1.38906143
5  0.20408723  0.51703237
6  0.58271061 -0.02246754
7  0.05170994  0.20583548
8  0.83627336  0.21530721
9  0.76713317  0.69087460
10 0.95052671  2.30610998

> df[-1,]
            y           x
2  0.15355851 -0.63098637
3  0.60098886 -1.30646529
4  0.14284576  1.38906143
5  0.20408723  0.51703237
6  0.58271061 -0.02246754
7  0.05170994  0.20583548
8  0.83627336  0.21530721
9  0.76713317  0.69087460
10 0.95052671  2.30610998

> df$x = NULL
> df 
            y
1  0.66658148
2  0.15355851
3  0.60098886
4  0.14284576
5  0.20408723
6  0.58271061
7  0.05170994
8  0.83627336
9  0.76713317
10 0.95052671
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's clear to @akz: in `header=T` the `T` stands for `TRUE`, so this parameter tells R to load header. See `?read.table` for details.

Comment: Note that if you have a single column data frame then please look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232770/4606130 where you will need a `drop = FALSE` as well when negative indexing

Answer (score 31):

You can use negative indexing to remove rows, e.g.:

```
dat <- dat[-1, ]
```

Here is an example:

```
> dat <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 1:3)
> dat[-1, ]
  A B
2 2 2
3 3 3
> dat2 <- dat[-1, ]
> dat2
  A B
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

That said, you may have more problems than just removing the labels that ended up on row 1. It is more then likely that R has interpreted the data as text and thence converted to factors. Check what `str(foo)`, where `foo` is your data object, says about the data types.

It sounds like you just need `header = TRUE` in your call to read in the data (assuming you read it in via `read.table()` or one of it's wrappers.)

Answer (score 27):

While I agree with the most voted answer, here is another way to keep all rows except the first:

```
dat <- tail(dat, -1)
```

This can also be accomplished using Hadley Wickham's `dplyr` package.

```
dat <- dat %>% slice(-1)
```

Answer (score 12):

No one probably really wants to remove row one. So if you are looking for something meaningful, that is conditional selection

```
#remove rows that have long length and "0" value for vector E

>> setNew<-set[!(set$length=="long" & set$E==0),]
```

Comment: This is an answer for a question that was not asked. I think it's more confusing than helping.

Answer (score 9):

I am not expert, but this may work as well,

```
dat <- dat[2:nrow(dat), ]
```

Comment: Actually this does not work when `nrow(dat) == 1`: Then the original dat is preserved.

Answer (score 6):

`dat <- dat[-1, ]` worked but it killed my dataframe, changing it into another type. Had to instead use 
`dat <- data.frame(dat[-1, ])` but this is possibly a special case as this dataframe initially had only one column.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer! Despite of that I could not reproduce.