# Remove a row from a data table in R

Tags: r

I have a data table with 5778 rows and 28 columns.  How do I delete ALL of the 1st row. E.g. let's say the data table had 3 rows and 4 columns and looked like this:

```
Row number tracking_id    3D71    3D72  3D73
    1          xxx         1       1     1
    2          yyy         2       2     2
    3          zzz         3       3     3
```

I want to create a data table that looks like this:

```
    Row number tracking_id    3D71    3D72  3D73
    1          yyy             2       2     2
    2          zzz             3       3     3
```

i.e. I want to delete all of row number 1 and then shift the other rows up.

I have tried `datatablename[-c(1)]` but this deletes the first column not the first row!

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: for data frames, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541610/how-to-delete-the-first-row-of-a-dataframe-in-r

Comment: `[row, column]` for data frames.  You obviously don't have a data table

Comment: `datatablename[-1, ]` works for both. why not be explicit with what you want, ie, use commas?

Comment: Yes I meant data frame not data table - sorry.  datatablename[-1,] worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this via

```
dataframename = dataframename[-1,]
```

Comment: This worked - thank you.  And yes sorry I meant data frame not data table.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done with indexing the data.table/data frame as mentioned by @joni. You can also do with

```
datatablename <- datatablename[2:nrow(datatablename), ]
```

You can find more interesting stuff about data.table [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html).