# How to delete the first row of a tibble

Tags: r, tibble

I want to delete the first row of a tibble. How do I do this? Can someone help?

Input

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

Output

```
A  B  C
4  5  6
```

I tried to do lapply with the subset function (choose from second element onwards) to each column of the tibble but it does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete the first row of a dataframe in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541610/how-to-delete-the-first-row-of-a-dataframe-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df <- df[-1,]
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(A = 4L, B = 5L, C = 6L), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```